# Redirect home to shared NTFS partition

Tags: directory-structure, defaults

I've installed windows 7 and linux dualboot. My partitions are:

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="EC328C61328C329E" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="800E88610E8851D8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="20e7c430-bab0-4aa1-8afe-caa9d97e1de3" TYPE="ext4"
```

where `sda2` is windows `sda3` is shared partition and `sda4` is linux

sd3 has mounting point `/windows`
Because `sda2` and `sda4` are small partitions I created directories Music, Documents, etc. and redirected windows libraries in here.
I want do the same in linux but editing `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`
to

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Plocha"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Šablony"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Veřejné"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/windows/home/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/windows/home/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/windows/home/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/windows/home/Videos"
```

has no effect. Folders has icons as it if works but when I click on Music in the file browser it goes to `/home/myUser/Music` not into`/windows/home/Music`.
It would be great if it would work for `cd ~/Music` command too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the lines as they were in original user-dirs.dirs :

```
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

And now create symbolic links to point to your windows folders (make sure you have no important data in the three concerned folders :

```
cd ~
rm -fr Music Pictures Videos
ln -s /windows/home/Music 
ln -s /windows/home/Pictures 
ln -s /windows/home/Videos
```

By the way, you would better create a swap partition. You don't mention you did it already.